# Getting error when producing messages to Open Sournce Apache Kafka Broker V0.9 on SSL

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

Created a dummy topic, and when producing messages using the command below
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list :port --topic dtopic --producer.config /tmp/ssl.properties

Getting below error.

[2017-06-01 15:31:36,414] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 0 : {dtopic=UNKNOWN} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Also seeing this below error in kafka broker log file..
[2017-06-01 15:45:38,925] ERROR [KafkaApi-0] error when handling request Name: TopicMetadataRequest; Version: 0; CorrelationId: 12; ClientId: console-producer; Topics: dtopic (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
kafka.common.BrokerEndPointNotAvailableException: End point SSL not found for broker 0

Comment: Below is the server configuration
   listeners=PLAINTEXT://<hostname>:<non-ssl port>,SSL://<hostname>:<ssl-port>
   ssl.keystore.location=<path to keystore>
   ssl.key.password=<password>
   ssl.keystore.password=<password>
   ssl.truststore.location=<trust store path>
   ssl.truststore.password=<password>
   security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
   ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2